# Move field from one profile type to another?

Tags: entities, users

I have a field in one profile type that really belongs in another profile type. The field already contains values.

I can imagine exporting the contents of the field, attaching a new instance of the field to the "other" profile, and importing the exported values to the new instance using feeds. But is there a more straightforward way to move a field (and existing values) from one profile type to another?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way. That means if you don't have a lot of records your better off doing it manually.

If you must:
   1. Add the field to profile type B.
   2. Change the nid in the field data and revision DB table for every user from the nid of profile A to the nid of profile B.
   3. Remove the field from profile type A.

Comment: I doubt that it would work well if the node revisions are enabled.It is not enough to change the nid in the field_revision table alone. That way the field revisions will be related to a non-existing vid (version ID) of the new node.